# Applying yaw rotation with torque causes object to continually spin when going upside down (fzero like)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have my ship be controllable within a tube-like level like in fzero. My problem is when the ship reaches the 90 degrees or more inside the tube to go upside down the ship will start to spin continuously and be uncontrollable. 
https://gph.is/g/Z5YYDnQ

```
//Calculate the yaw torque based on the rudder and current angular velocity
    float rotationTorque = input.rudder - rigidBody.angularVelocity.y; //input.rudder = horizontal 
axis from key
    //Apply the torque to the ship's Y axis
     rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(0f, rotationTorque, 0f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Comment: Not sure, but you may be experiencing so-called [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) as you handle 3-value eulerAngles instead of 4-value Quaternions. Or maybe errors of exceeding the 0/ 360 edge. Note Unity converts your eulerAngles to a Quaternion. They [say](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) to avoid problems, the way to "work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation", then offering some tips. Good luck!